# Compare files in different folders

Tags: java, eclipse, diff, cvs

I'm using cvs (not by choice) and I refactored a project by creating a new package hierarchy in a v2 branch. Now i need to merge the changes that happened in branch v1 into branch v2. But because the files' path changed i can't do a normal compare. Is there some way to do this in eclipse (or in any other tool)? i know in general, there's no way to know for sure if the files have the same origin just by using the filename; this is a non-issue for me since all the filenames are unique in my case. I know I can go and manually select the two files and do a diff but i have too many classes to make this feasible. I am looking for an automatic pairing of the files just like when a file has changed where the tool detects the diff automatically

Does anyone have any other suggestions to do such a merge in a crappy VCS?

**Update:**
Some explanation of the changes I made might make it clearer

```
v1
Folder1
   file1
   file2
   file3
   file4
   file5
```

---

```
v2
FolderA
   file1
   FolderA1
      file2
      FolderA11
          file3
   FolderA2
      file4
FolderB
   file5
```

So, as can be seen, there's no pattern in the movements. It is just a completely new hierarchy of what was before a flat hierarchy. That means i can't do a folder diff. What I want is something that pairs v1:folder1/file4 with v2:FolderA/FolderA2/file4 for example so that i can just see the change in content without caring for the fact that the file was moved. In other words, a path-less diff that just uses the filename to match files

Comment: With Bash scripts (`ls -lR | grep ....`) you can do the magic. To get Bash shell on Windows, use `Cygwin`.

Comment: that has been my best idea so far as well: writing a bash script but i thought of using `find` to match the two files with the same name and then diff. The only problem is that this will show the diff but won't let me merge the changes easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this shell script snippet:

```
ls -R /path/to/source1 | grep '.java\|.js\|.css' | grep -v ':$' >allfiles.txt
ls -R /path/to/source2 | grep '.java\|.js\|.css' | grep -v ':$' >>allfiles.txt
cat allfiles.txt | sort | uniq -d > same_files.txt
cat allfiles.txt | sort | uniq -u > different_files.txt

# This will compare the same files one-by-one
for i in `cat same_files.txt`; do 
    FILE1=`find /path/to/source1 -name $i`; 
    FILE2=`find /path/to/source2 -name $i`;
    diff -q $FILE1 $FILE2 
done
```

The trick is the `uniq` command, and its special switches. `-d` leaves only the duplicates, `-u` sorts out the duplicates.

To run on Windows, use `Cygwin`: http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd download both branches and use a compare tool like http://winmerge.org/ to compare local directories.

Comment: i can't do a dir-for-dir compare since the contents are different. I will update the question with an example

Comment: Maybe then you can copy all files to the same folder,one folder for each branch, and do the comparison there. (you said file names were different, right?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a lib i have writen.
It can compare the content of 2 folders, an give u true/false or the differenc between them in detail.
(SubFolders are also compared with their content)

Here is the link:
https://badandmadstudio.wordpress.com/projects/dircompare-java/